# Expo error errno: -4094, node:events:492 > npx expo start

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at Walker._checkedEmitError (E:\HomeFit\for-better\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:134:12)
    at Walker.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at E:\HomeFit\for-better\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
```

**Error: I don't know why, but until a week ago, everything was fine. Then when I tried to run 'npx expo start' again, I received this error.**

Suddenly I got an error like this

1. i try deleted node_modules
2. i try npm install
3. i try npm start -- -- reset cache

I tried these and it still doesn't work